# Why do some docker images require a command when run?

Tags: docker

I find when using `docker run` I sometimes don't need to add a "command", while sometimes a "command" is a must. E.g. when running the `ubuntu` image a command isn't required:

```
# docker run ubuntu
#
```

While when running `mstormo/suse`:

```
# docker run mstormo/suse
Error response from daemon: No command specified
# docker run mstormo/suse bash
#
```

So is this related to the specified image?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Docker image can optionally [include a default command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) to run when none is given on the command-line.

If no default command is given, then it has to be provided by the caller.

If you look at the [Dockerfile for ubuntu](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/30d456fb9b0b00f204f30a4ef84217bf59620b17/precise/Dockerfile), they have

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

So if you don't say otherwise, it will run `bash` for you.

No such setting in [mstormo/suse](https://hub.docker.com/r/mstormo/suse/~/dockerfile/).

Comment: So although from [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/run/) page:`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`, the command seems **optional**, but actually it should be **must**, right?

Comment: Well, as far as docker is concerned, it is optional. But the image may want one (and it may also want some args).

Comment: The error you are getting about the missing command is not coming from docker. It is coming from the entrypoint binary inside of the image.